# How to create a newsletter partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a very simple email signup form, where the user can just enter their email and press submit.

I'd like the signup form to be a partial, so I can use it anywhere on the site.

Forms are coded like this:
`<%= form_for @subscription do |f| %>`

How to do tell the form that `@subscription` is a `Subscription.new` if, say, the current view, controller, and action is the home page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an option you can do:

```
<%= form_for Subscription.new do |f| %>
```

One thing though, I haven't tried this myself. Try it and see if it works.

**Edit:**

Sorry, I didn't get the question in the first read.
You can set the `@subscription` instance variable to `Subscription.new` in the home controller, and then, pass it to the partial (inside the main view) like this:

```
<%= render partial, :subscription => @subscription %>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make sure that `@subscription` is instantiated before calling the partial ... or do :

```
 <%= form_for @subscription || Subscription.new do |f| %>
```

So if `@subscription` exists, it uses it. If not, it'll fall back to `Subscription.new`

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `@subscription` as `Subscription.new` right in the home action